# O programa não está lendo os números da matriz

Tags: c, syntax-error

Estou fazendo exercícios no uri online judge, este pede:

Neste problema você deve ler um número, indicando uma linha da matriz na qual uma operação deve ser realizada, um caractere maiúsculo, indicando a operação que será realizada, e todos os elementos de uma matriz `M[12][12]`.

Em seguida, calcule e mostre a soma ou a média dos elementos que estão na área verde da matriz, conforme for o caso. A primeira linha de entrada contem um número L indicando a linha que será considerada para operação. A segunda linha de entrada contém um único caractere Maiúsculo T ('S' ou 'M'), indicando a operação (Soma ou Média) que deverá ser realizada com os elementos da matriz.

Seguem os 144 valores de ponto flutuante que compõem a matriz, sendo que a mesma é preenchida linha por linha, da linha 0 até a linha 11, sempre da esquerda para a direita.

Saída

Imprima o resultado solicitado (a soma ou média), com 1 casa após o ponto decimal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

    float M[12][12];
    int linha, l, coluna;
    char T;
    float calculo;

    scanf("%d", &l);
    scanf("%c", &T);

    for(linha = 0; linha < 12; linha ++){
        for(coluna = 0; coluna < 12; coluna ++){
            scanf("%f", &M[linha][coluna]);
        }
    }

    if (T == 'M'){
        for(coluna = 0; coluna < 12; coluna ++){
            calculo = calculo + M[l][coluna];
        }
        calculo = calculo/12;
    }
    else {
        for (coluna = 0; coluna < 12; coluna ++){
            calculo = calculo + M[l][coluna];
        }
    }
    printf ("%0.1f", calculo);


}
```

O programa não lê a matriz e dá erro. Agradeço quem quiser me ajudar, obrigada :)

Comment: Isso é q linguagem? Procure sempre que possivel identificar qual linguagem se trata a pergunta.

Comment: Parece me C. Mas isso não chega

Comment: Desculpa gente, é em linguagem C

Answer (score 2):

Quando sai do `scanf("%d",&l)` o código está armazenando buffer da quebra de linha e pula o `scanf("%c",T)`, ou seja, ele pula direto para o `scanf("%f", &M[][])` dentro do for, então quando você insere um carácter da erro.
tente ler o carácter assim

```
scanf("\n%c",&T);
```

Com isso, quando você digitar `<n>[enter]`, vai identificar que tem uma quebra de linha antes de ler um valor para T.